# Red markings in reviewboard

Tags: javascript, review-board

Does anyone knows what these red markings in reviewboard mean ?
I've seen them popping up inconsistently.

The showing file is a .html file in an csproj, it contains a JavaScript underscore template.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was also searching for the same and got this link

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/reviewboard/sOR_-EGmDok ,

where they say that it is because of the pygments  which is the highlighter reviewboard uses internally. I went ahead searching for to validate this answer and found that it was a pygments problem failing to recognize utf8 characters .

please see

1) https://code.google.com/p/minted/issues/detail?id=55

2) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14166/red-box-drawn-around-question-mark-operator-in-minted-erlang-code

both support the answer posted in the google groups link .

Comment: Thanks for your response, i deduce from your answer that the html specific syntax checking has issues with the template characters. I don't think the problem for this specific file is UTF related.